# Adding Answer Button To Twilio Client

Tags: php, twilio

This might sound like a stupid question but i'm going through the client quickstart tutorials and i want to know how to require a button click to answer on the client side. 
on example: hello-client-monkey-3.php 
it just picks up after one ring, i would like to add a pick up button on the page? 
how can i do this?

I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
function answer() {
    Twilio.Device.accept();
}

<button onclick="answer();">
    Answer
</button>
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the 'device' that can accept the call, it's the connection. From [the docs](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device#incoming):

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connection) {
  connection.accept();
  // do awesome ui stuff here
  // $('#call-status').text("you're on a call!");
});
```

So your answer button has to know about the `connection` not the `Device`. Probably best to create the answer button when `Twilio.Device` has a new incoming connection, and then `onclick` accept that **specific** connection.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have figured it out now with your post. If you do not mind, I have posted another problem I am having here. Can you please take a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300530/twilio-client-mute-button-not-working

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get my head around this either. The lovely people at Twilio provided me with this answer:

There are a couple ways I've seen it done. One way is to store the incoming connection in a temporary variable, e.g. `incoming_conn`

```
  var incoming_conn = null;

  Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connection) {
    incoming_conn = connection;
  });

  function accept() {
    if (incoming_conn) {
      incoming_conn.accept();
      accepted_conn = incoming_conn;
      incoming_conn = null;
    }
  }
```

(Me) Then you will need to call that function from your UI:

```
  <button onclick="accept();">
      Answer
  </button>
```

Another way would be to attach a click handler to the accept button, which is easier if you use jQuery, e.g.

```
  Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connection) {
    $("#answer").click(function() {
        connnect.accept();
    });
```

That assumes your button has class "answer":

```
<button id="answer">
    Answer
</button>
```