# Twilio Client "Mute" button not working

Tags: php, javascript, twilio

I am having a problem "Muting" an outgoing call through Twilio Client. I am able to mute calls when I receive an *incoming* call, however, when I make an *outgoing* call, the mute button does not work. I have tried everything I can think of to make this mute button work but nothing I do works. Here is a link with the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call() {
     //Get the phone number to connect the call to
     params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
     Twilio.Device.connect(params);

     $("#mute").click(function() {
        conn.mute();
     });

 }
</script>

<button id="mute">
     Mute
</button>
```

Please help with this. It has been driving me crazy. I cannot figure this out! Thanks

Comment: I have faced the same problem too. 

var myConnection;
device.on('connect', function (conn) {
  myConnection = conn;
  myConnection.mute(true); //not working, still can hear the endpoint's audio
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be setting `conn = Twilio.Device.connect(params);`?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#connect